# Export From Teradata Table to CSV

Tags: teradata

Is it possible to transfer the date from the Teradata Table into .csv file directly.
Problem is - my table has more that 18 million rows.
If yes, please send tell me the process

Answer (score 3):

For a table that size I would suggest using the FastExport utility. It does not natively support a CSV export but you can mimic the behavior.

Teradata SQL Assistant will export to a CSV but it would not be appropriate to use with a table of that size.

BTEQ is another alternative that may be acceptable for a one-time dump if the table.

Do you have access to any of these?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to change the delimiter of exported text files within Teradata SQL Assistant, without needing any separate applications:

Go to **Tools > Options > Export/Import**. From there, you can change the **Use this delimiter between column** option from {Tab} to ','.

You might also want to set the 'Enclose column data in' option to 'Double Quote', so that any commas in the data itself don't upset the file structure.

[image: Export/Import Settings]

From there, you use the regular text export: **File > Export Results**, run the query, and select one of the **Delimited Text** types.

[image: File Type Selection]

Then you can just use your operating system to manually change the file extension from .txt to **.csv**.

These instructions are from SQL Assistant version 16.20.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to export data from the Teradata Table into `.csv` file directly.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 
database_name.table_name (to be created) SAMEAS database_name.table_name (already existing, whose data is to be exported)
USING (DATAOBJECT ('C:\Data\file_name.csv')
DELIMITER '|' REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC');
```

Comment: How fast is this? I mean for a "big" table as mentioned in the question?

Comment: This is not valid Teradata syntax.

Comment: I don't think you can create an external table in TD on a single drive, given this is almost always a cluster of physical nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FastExport utility from Teradata Studio for exporting the table in CSV format. You can define the delimiter as well.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

Basic idea would be to export first table as a TXT file and then converting TXT t o CSV using R...read.table ()---> write.csv().....

Below are the steps of exporting TD table as txt file:

- Select export option from file

[image]

- Select all records from the table you want to export

[image]

- Save it as a TXT file

[image]

Then use ***R to convert TXT file to CSV*** (set working directory to the location where you have saved your big TXT file):

```
my_table<-read.table("File_name.txt", fill = TRUE, header = TRUE)
write.csv(my_table,file = "File_name.csv")
```

This had worked for 15 million records table. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know which release of SQL Assistant you're using, but there's a *Delimited Tex*t option in my version. And of course fastest way wuld be a simple TPT Export using DELIMITED format.